# Running infinite loops in Flask route

Tags: html, python-3.x, user-interface, flask, infinite-loop

I'm working with a Flask app that has to run an infinite function called `session` inside the route `/init`. Because `session` is infinite, when i have the code lay out like

```
@app.route('/init', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
def init():
    session(stock, batch_size, wait_time)
    return render_template('init.html', stock=stock, batch_size=batch_size, wait_time=wait_time)
```

the template will never get rendered. When I switch `session` and the `return` function, the template gets rendered but of course `session` never runs.

The reason `session` has to run infinitely is because it relies on real time info, and thus has to check for new info every `wait_time`. I want to be able to run `session` and update the HTML using the output (which will change every `wait_time`). I am extremely new to web dev, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

If it's any help, [here's the full code on GitHub.](https://github.com/AllHailTheSheep/StockMonitor)

Thanks.

Comment: HTTP isn't really meant for that kind of use case. Instead you'll probably want to use something like websockets: [Websockets in Flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23111654/websockets-in-flask)

Comment: what did you end up doin for this?